# SearchView with ViewPager in two fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, searchview

I have the below line of code in two consecutive fragments:

```
 MenuItem searchItem=  menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    searchView =
            (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setEnabled(true);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(searchQueryListener);
```

It searches correctly. Trouble is, it only searches in the fragment with that line of code instantiated later (later position on the ViewPager). I know this because if I remove it from the second fragment it will work in the first one. Any ideas on how to get this search function to work in both fragments?

Edit 1: let me clarify. The fragments are in two separate classes and will be used to search two different adapters.

Edit 2:

I have a really awful workaround right now...
I use a statepageradapter for a fixed number of screens and then I place the fragments more than 1 apart on app launch....

Why is this so difficult? This should not be like this. Why would would a menu that can't be seen be instantiated?